# Issue in datepicker Lock dates in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two datepickers one is strat date & oyher is end date
When I select the start date ,the dates before the start dates in end datepicker should get locked bautomatically..
I written like this,

```
$('#ProjectsMaster_startdate').datepicker({
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
        });
        $('#ProjectsMaster_enddate').datepicker({
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates,
        });


function DisableSpecificDates(date)
    {
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        var currdate = new Date(y, m, d);//Year, Month (starts from 0-11), Date   
        var start_date_val = new Date($("#ProjectsMaster_startdate").val());
        var disableddate = new Date(start_date_val);
        if (currdate <= disableddate)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But I am facing a problem,
**The dates in the end date is getting locked when i click it twice But its not working on single click**
Plz anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you trying to setup start date and end date functionality, Try following:

Select start date and onClose funtion set min date for end-date.

```
   //Jquery Caendar
    $(".start-date").datepicker({
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $(".end-date").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $(".end-date").datepicker({
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $(".start-date").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
```